# javabean list of possible values of property

Tags: java, swing, javabeans

i want to create a Bean where you can choose value of the property form dropdown list (limited possibilities) like in this case:

[image: dropdown for bean property]

i want to have a ability to limit number of colors that user can choose to two, red and blue. my property is type `Java.awt.Color`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The boolean property editor is a menu of discrete choices that overrides the PropertyEditorSupport.getTags method to return a String[] containing "True" and "False":

```
public String[] getTags() {
    String result[] = { "True", "False" };
    return result;
}
```

"

This is mechanism to do a discrete list of values of Bean. It is needed to override that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a JavaBean then the setter methods are responsible for validating the arguments. If the arguments are not valid then you throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
public class ListProperty {
    private Color color
    //Other properties you like.

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        if (Color.RED.equals(color) || Color.BLUE.equals(color) {
            this.color = color;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The color is not red or blue.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You see, that is not a elegant way of doing it. That example was from JButton bean property, i want something more like that, elegant and easy to use.

Comment: This is the recommended way of doing this. That's why you have setter methods in a JavaBean, only for validating passed arguments.

Comment: I understand your idea of controlling passed value, i should do it too in my setProperty function. First of all i want get that dropdown effect AND then i have to check value in set function in case that someone will try pass illegal argument.

Answer (score 0):

I guess using an Enum is the best way here.Since you can restrict the options based on your definition of the Enum you have tight control

Comment: I'll try your option. I was consodering that way of doing it.